# Google Drive API changes thumbnailLink value on every GET request?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, image-scaling

I'm uploading some images to our GDrive account (via API) so I can publish them in our webapp.

I like to post **thumbnailLink** because of the `=s` parameter where you can scale the image to a desire width.

But now I've found a problem:

- everytime I make a file get request (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) the thumbnailLink changes its value

This problem raises two questions:

1. Why does this happen?
2. Is there anyway I can keep the same **thumbnailLink** and make it
   work forever?

edition: in file documentation (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files) says that only **downloadUrl** has a short lived value

Comment: Did you find a solution for that? I wanted to use the thumbnaillink for the very same reason...

Comment: no, I've quit using Google Drive

Answer (score 1):

The thumbnail URL is also short lived (as some simple testing revealed). I'll work with the documentation team to also have this noted in the documentation.